# yii routing with parrameters

Tags: php, yii, routes

I spent pretty much time on it already and I'm starting to give up so... help me understand it please

I'm trying to make my URLs very short and it works fine with URLs without parameter but those with parameter does not work.

In my routing setting I have:

```
'rules'=>array( 
        'kontakt' => 'site/contact',
        'faq' => 'site/page/view/faq',
...
```

Then when I use in zii.widgets.CMenu (or in Chtml::link()) links as array for the first rule then it's ok but for second not. So to be more precise

**This works**

```
array('label'=>'Kontakt', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
```

it generates http://mysite.com/kontakt URL which is what I expected.

**But this doesn't work**

```
array('label'=>'FAQ', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'faq')),
```

i generates mysite.com/site/page/view/faq and I want it to generate simply mysite.com/faq.

I've read a lot and tried a lot of variations but it fails all the time... any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be something like:

```
    '<view>' => 'site/page',
```

This means that if you generate a url to site/page that has a view parameter, then it'll just go to view.  The rule will get skipped if you don't have a view parameter.

Comment: Thanks... this works indeed but now I realized that I gave a bit wrong example... I want to do also a SEO URL translation here... something like this '<view:(questions)>' => 'site/page/<view:(faq)>'... so what I want to achieve is to have different URL than the view value itself. It works for the first example I gave above with "contact" so I believe it's possible with params URLs as well?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want; your pseudo-code isn't making any sense to me.

Comment: When I create URL array('/site/page', 'view'=>'faq')) I want Yii to generate http://mysite.com/questions link... that is simply all what I want.